# How to do a string comparison ignore whitespace?

Tags: bash, string

How would you compare two strings but ignoring whitespaces? I am doing the following:

```
if [ "$a" == "$b" ]; then
   echo ok
fi
```

But it doesn't seem to match. I've printed what "a" and "b" are and they are the same. It seems that they are using different newline characters though.

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) first and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: You should know that [`==` is not a standard comparison operator,](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_bar_.3D.3D_.22.24foo.22_.5D) but is a Bash extension.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, to ignore all whitespace you could pass both strings through `tr`:

```
[ "$(echo "$a" | tr -d '[:space:]')" = "$(echo "$b" | tr -d '[:space:]')" ]
```

However, this way all whitespace gets removed before the comparison, so for example `"a b"` and `"ab"` will test equal. I'm not sure this is desirable. You can tweak the `tr` filter to do what you need. For instance, to remove only newlines of all flavours, you can do `tr -d '\n\r'`.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can use a [parameter expansion syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to take the value of a variable with some characters removed (or more generally replacing occurrences of a pattern).

```
if [[ "${a//[$' \t\n\r']/}" == "${b//[$' \t\n\r']/}" ]]; then
  echo ok
fi
```

If the problem is that they're “using different newline characters”, that probably means that one of them is coming from a Windows file. Windows lines have an extra CR (carriage return, `$'\r` in bash syntax) before the newline character (`$'\n'`). If you have multiline strings, you can strip off just the CR characters:

```
if [[ "${a//$'\r'/}" == "${b//$'\r'/}" ]]; then
  echo ok
fi
```

If the variables are single-line strings then the troublesome CR would be at the end and you can use the suffix stripping syntax:

```
if [[ "${a%$'\r'}" == "${b%$'\r'}" ]]; then
  echo ok
fi
```

If you need this one in plain sh, the (minor) difficulty is entering a CR character.

```
cr=$(printf '\r')
if [[ "${a%$cr}" == "${b%$cr}" ]]; then
  echo ok
fi
```